# vs code and intellisense for CSS Grid and CSS Modules

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, intellisense, css-grid, css-modules

I am using VS code for a project using CSS Grid and CSS Modules.  However when I try something like this

```
.loginRegisterDiv {
  composes: loginDiv;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I get an error saying composes "unknown property" for composes.  Plus I am using css grid and there does not seem to be any intellisense for this in VS code.  Do I need to install an extension?

I am using rallycoding rulesets.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Still no solution? I'm getting the same error when using CSS Grid.

Comment: @comfortablyNumb - I use extensions to solve this. Check the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 13):

This works to me, in your `settings.json` file add `"css.lint.validProperties": ["composes"],`

Comment: Perfect fix, so easy

Comment: Very easy fix, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can add to the VSC CSS linter an exception to the rule `css.lint.unknownProperties` (or set this to ignore). Open the VSC settings, search for `css.lint.validProperties` and add 'composes' to the list. The error/warning will go away.

Answer (score 2):

I use extensions to help with this particular problem. The extension system is excellent in VS Code, and there are a lot of really high quality extensions built by the community that greatly improve the quality and feature set of the editor.

Here are a few extensions that I use for writing SASS in VS Code. One or a couple of these should fix the problems you are having (and maybe even a few you didn't know you were having).

- [SCSS Grammar Extended](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dannymcgee.scss-grammar-extended) *by Danny McGee*

  - **Features:**

    - Fixes content and cursor property names being tokenized as tag selectors
    - Fixes background being tokenized as an invalid/deprecated keyword in certain contexts
    - Fixes color being tokenized as a property value keyword instead of a property name in certain contexts
    - null and boolean values tokenized as language constants
    - BEM-style __element and --modifier fragments tokenized as class names
    - Added recognition for Angular-specific pseudo-selectors :host-context and ::ng-deep
- [Sass](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Syler.sass-indented) *by Syler*

  - **Features:**

    - Upgraded syntax highlighting
    - AutoCompletions / Intellisense
    - Formatter
- [CSS Modules Syntax Highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andrewleedham.vscode-css-modules) *by Andrew Leedham*

  - **Features:**

    - @value variable decleration: regular and namespaced.
    - composes: attribute: local and imports.
    - :global and :local pseudo classes.
- [SCSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss#review-details) *by mrmlnc*

  - **Features:**

    - Code Completion Proposals (variables, mixins, functions)
    - Hover (variables, mixins, functions)
    - Code navigation

Install one or several of those in VS Code, restart the editor, and then let me know if that doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you, CSS Modules Syntax Highlighter works great!

Answer (score 2):

To make the VS Code recognise these custom CSS directive/properties, you can provide custom data for VS Code's CSS Language Service as mentioned here - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/docs/customData.md.

Create a CSS custom data set file with the following info. Place it at location `.vscode/custom.css-data.json` relative to the project root.

```json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "composes",
      "description": "css modules compose"
    }
  ],
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@value",
      "description": "css modules value import"
    }
  ],
  "pseudoClasses": [],
  "pseudoElements": []
}
```

Now, if you don't have already, create a `.vscode\settings.json` file relative to project root. Add a field with key "css.customData" and value as the path to custom data set. For example,

```json
{
  "css.customData": ["./.vscode/custom.css-data.json"]
}
```

Now, you will no longer get "Unknown property" warning. When you hover over "composes", you will see the description you set for it in `custom.css-data.json`

[image: "css modules compose" shown in tooltip when "composes" is hovered]

Comment: can this also help with autocompletion of the values in composes

Comment: @gaurav5430 For this use case we have created a vs code extension to autosuggest the classNames which can be composed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been raised to the vs code team and has not been addressed yet:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13003

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for Sass, In my `styles.module.scss` file:

[image]

Just go to Settings > Extensions > CSS Language Features > SCSS (Sass)
or Search `SCSS Lint Valid Properties` & Add Item `composes`

[image]

or add `"scss.lint.validProperties": [ "composes" ]` in [`settings.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-to-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)

[image]
<sub>and *Voilà* the warning is finally gone!</sub>