# Importing scss module classes using the 'composes' property in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, sass

In Next.js 13, how can I use the `composes` property of css modules in my scss module files?

Example:

```scss
// specific.module.scss
.MySpecificClass {
    composes: MyGenericClass from "./generic.module.scss";
 }
```

The error is get is:

> Unknown property: 'composes' scss(unknownProperties)

Comment: have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520229/vs-code-and-intellisense-for-css-grid-and-css-modules?